# How to make only a part of a View (which is added at runtime) overlay/overlap the neighbouring views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-overlay

LHS of the following disagram shows the initial structure of the `Activity` set up in XML, and the RHS shows the `Activity` after some runtime changes.

The black border encloses the `RelativeLayout` (*I can change it to `LinearLayout` or something else if that solves my problem*) which is the root of the Activity's layout, the red border encloses a `RecyclerView`, the green border inside it encloses an element of the RecyclerView. The dark blue border encloses a `FrameLayout` to which a `Fragment` will be added at runtime.

**Now the thing is that at runtime, some more elements are added to the red bordered `RecyclerView`**, collectively shown by purple-bordered box in the RHS of the diagram. **Only the part of the `RecyclerView` containing these newly added elements should overlay the rest of the `Activity`'s content (i.e. essentially the `FrameLayout`)**

So what kind of layout should I use as the root of the Activity, how should I make this part-of-a-layout-overlapping-the-neighbours thingy possible? **How should I go about it?** Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So your question is to how to achieve the xml to do what is described in the images above? If that's the case, you'll need to guarantee that the height of the green box is always the same - in which case you can set the blue box's `layout_height=match_parent` but add `layout_marginTop=[static_height_of_green_box]`. Also make sure the red box is marked up below the blue box.

Comment: @ElliotM Firstly, thank you indeed! _"If that's the case, you'll need to guarantee that the height of the green box is always the same"_ it is always the same, but is `wrap_content`, while the content is Not dynamic. So the height of the green box does always remain the same, and what it contains is a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing an `ImageView`, an `EditText`, and an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout` you can achieve overlap layout.

However it may need more details to know which is best for you.

Edit:

If the green layout is having fixed height, say, `100dp`, seems you could easily get what you want with RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:height="match_parent"
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>
    <RecyclerView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey nice edit! Two things: it's `layout_marginTop` and I believe you have to move the `RecyclerView` xml below the `FrameLayout` xml otherwise the `FrameLayout` will get rendered on top

Comment: @ElliotM _" you have to move the RecyclerView xml below the FrameLayout xml otherwise the FrameLayout will get rendered on top"_ but why will the `FrameLayout` get rendered at the top, when it occurs after the `RecyclerView` in the view hierarchy (i.e. its XML element is written after the XML element of the `RecyclerView`) within the parent `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the answer. I like the solution, it had also occured to me, but unfortunately the `layout_height` of the `RecyclerView` is `wrap_content` so I can't probably go that way =(

Comment: @Solace, the later the view in the layout, the later it is rendered, so the later will be on the top.

Comment: @DerekFung Ooh OK OK I get it. Thanks

Comment: @Solace, actually what you want to display on the RecyclerView? It sounds strange to me to have RecyclerView with wrap_content, it sounds more like a LinearLayout to me

Comment: @DerekFung No no no, it's not a RecyclerView with the `wrap_content` height, it is a row of the RecyclerView (a `ViewHolder`) having that height. Initially, it is just this one row, later other rows will be added.

Comment: ic, maybe you have to consider to set the marginTop programmatically with global layout listener

Comment: @DerekFung Actually I tried set a `android:marginTop="35dp"` (just shooting in the air) on the `RecyclerView`, which gave me an idea that I need to increase it a bit, then I tried `50dp` and it is the perfect `marginTop` I needed. I think that's called bootstrapping. =P I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: Glad that this helped you more or less :)